# Customizing suggestions in a text view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a `textview`. When we are editing a `textview`, we can see suggestions as shown in the image. I want to customize the suggestions. ie, Instead of the default words in suggestion box, I want to show words from my array. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicated [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522043/uitextview-custom-auto-completion)

Answer (score 1):

To disable suggestion there are 2 methods:

First one is:

```
UITextField* f = [[UITextField alloc] init];
f.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Second one is:
The Interface Builder also has a dropdown field to disable this. As you're more likely to create textfields in the interface builder, look for it there. You can find it in the Attributes Inspector next to 'Correction'.

For your array in suggestions go through this link:https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/autocompletiontableview

Answer (score 0):

Disable autocorrect for that text view, then have a custom view ready and place it above the other views matching wherever the cursor is. There's probably other SO posts to find out where that cursor is...

You'll probably use the delegate pattern 2-way. One way, the custom view is made aware of changes in the UITextView so it knows when to update itself's suggestions.

The other delegate is your view or the textView, notified when someone hits the button.

This should all be easy to make, the only hard part is figuring out how your custom view's logic will behave